# What is the difference between "make it up to" and "make amends"?

Tags: word-usage

It seems both "***make it up to***" and "***make amends***" have same meaning.

Is there any difference?

Comment: You _make it up to_ a person you have offended, but you _make amends for_ something you have done wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You "make it up" **to** one or more people; you make amends **for** something you have done.

If you have offended or disadvantaged someone, you can "make it up to" them - do something to compensate them; I changed Tom's working hours, but I made it up to him by letting him go home early on Fridays.

[Make it up to somebody (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make-it-up-to-sb)

If you have done something to someone that is wrong or harmful, you can "make amends for" the action usually by doing something good to show that you are sorry; she tried to make amends by buying him a drink.

[Make amends (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/amends?q=make%20amends)

Comment: I don't disagree, but answers lacking authoritative references are not of a standard ELU expects.